# On polynomials over finite ring

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, finite-rings

Let $R$ be a finite commutative ring with unity ; then does there exist a non-empty proper subset $A \subseteq R$ and $f(X) \in R[X]$ such that $f(r)=1 , \forall r \in A$ and $f(r)=0 , \forall r \notin A$ ?

Comment: It is true when $R$ is a field, because of Lagrange interpolation formula.

Comment: @lhf : That I know ... but there are lots and lots of non-field finite rings , and I am not even sure whether my claim is true for finite local rings or not .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such an $f$ exists iff $R$ is local.

First, suppose $R$ is local.  Since $R$ is finite, its unique maximal ideal is the nilradical, so every element of $R$ is either nilpotent or a unit.  There is then some $n$ such that $r^n=0$ for every nilpotent $n$ and $r^n=1$ for every unit $r$.  You can then take $f(X)=X^n$.

Now suppose $R$ is not local.  Equivalently, this means either $R$ is the zero ring (in which case $R$ has no nonempty proper subsets) or $R$ is isomorphic to a direct product $S\times T$ of two nontrivial rings $S$ and $T$.  Then given any $f\in R[X]$, consider its images $f_S\in S[X]$ and $f_T\in T[X]$.  Note that the set of values which $f$ takes is the product of the set of values $f_S$ takes and the set of values $f_T$ takes.  So the set of values $f$ takes must be a "rectangle" in the product $S\times T$.  But since $S$ and $T$ both have more than one element, the set $\{0,1\}=\{(0,0),(1,1)\}\subset R$ is not a rectangle, so it cannot be the set of values taken by any polynomial.

Comment: How do you get $r^n=1$ in a local ring ?

Comment: Because the ring is finite, you can choose $n$ to be a multiple of the orders of all the units.

Comment: $\exists n >0$ such that If $r$ is not a unit then $r^n=0$ , holds in any Artinian local ring ... and given a local ring $(R,m)$ , $\exists k >0$ such that If $r$ is a unit then $r^k=1$ , holds if the group $R^{\times}=R \setminus m$ has bounded exponent ... so what are all Artinian local rings $(R,m)$ such that the multiplicative group of units $R \setminus m$ has bounded exponent ? Definitely , by first Prufer theorem , $R^{\times} = R \setminus m$ must be a direct sum of finite cyclic groups ... but is there a more nice characterization ?

Comment: Only the finite Artinian local rings.  If $R^\times$ has bounded exponent, then so does $(R/m)^\times$, since it is a quotient of $R^\times$.  That means $R/m$ is finite, and then $R$ is finite since it is finite length as a module over itself and the only simple module is $R/m$.

Comment: Do you think that for any local ring , with finite residue field , of Krull dimension $0$ , we can get a $\{0,1\}$ valued polynomial ?

Comment: Do you have any idea about this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2406486/polynomial-over-local-ring-with-finite-residue-field-of-krull-dimension-0  ?

Answer (score 1):

So effectively, you're asking this question:

- $\;$Given a finite ring $R$, is there always some polynomial $f \in R[x]$ such that $f(R)=\{0,1\}$?

For a counterexample, take $R = Z_6$, and suppose $f \in R[x]$ is such that $f(R)=\{0,1\}$.

Suppose $f(a) = 1$ and $f(b) = 0$.

Let $r \in R$.

If $r$ has the same parity as $a$, then $f(r)$ has the same parity as $f(a)$, hence $f(r)=1$.

Similarly, if $r$ has the same parity as $b$, then $f(r)$ has the same parity as $f(b)$, hence $f(r)=0$.

It follows that either 
$$f(0) = f(2) = f(4) = 1\;\;\text{and}\;\;f(1) = f(3) = f(5) = 0$$
$$\text{or}$$
$$f(0) = f(2) = f(4) = 0\;\;\text{and}\;\;f(1) = f(3) = f(5) = 1$$
But then we have a contradiction, since $f(0)$ must be congruent to $f(3),\;$mod $3$.