# Polynomial over local ring ( with finite residue field ) of Krull dimension $0$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension, local-rings

Let $(R,m)$ be a local ring of Krull dimension $0$ such that the residue field $R/m$ is finite ; then is it true that $\exists f(X) \in R[X]$ such that $f(R)=\{f(r) : r \in R \}= \{0,1\}$ ?

If we also assume that $m^n=0$ for some $n>0$ i.e. that say $m$ is a nilpotent ideal , then I can show the claim is true .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k$ be a finite field and let $R=k[x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots]/(x_1^2,x_2^4,x_3^8,\dots)$.  Then $R$ satisfies all your hypotheses.  However, if $f(X)\in R[X]$, then $f$ involves only finitely many of the variables $x_i$.  Let $n$ be such that the variable $x_n$ does not appear in $f$ and $\deg f<2^n$.  Then since the only relation involving $x_n$ is $x_n^{2^n}$, $f(x_n)$ can only be equal to $0$ or $1$ if it is a constant polynomial.  So there is no $f$ such that $f(x_n)\in \{0,1\}$ for all $n$ and both values $0$ and $1$ are in the image of $f$.

Comment: Okay ... so in the end , can such an $f$ exist ? I didn't get that ...

Comment: Oops, I forgot the key word "no" in the last sentence.

Comment: Could you please give some explanations as to why $R$ satisfies all my hypothesis ... ?

Comment: In this context, isn’t it part of the definition of *local ring* that the ring be noetherian?

Comment: @Lubin : Um no ... a local ring here is just a commutative ring with unity with unique maximal ideal

Comment: Thanks for that. I prefer the nonnoetherian ones myself.

Comment: @users: Since each $x_n$ is nilpotent, $m=(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)$ is contained in all prime ideals of $R$.  But $R/m\cong k$ is a field, so $m$ is a maximal ideal.  So $m$ is the unique prime ideal of $R$, and moreover the quotient $R/m$ is a finite field.